# React native useEffect() hook releated

Tags: react-native

```
 useEffect(() => {skylinkEventManager.addEventListener(events.ON_INCOMING_STREAM, response => {
            console.log('ON_INCOMING_STREAM', response, true);
        });
```

this eventListener is executing for two times. how can i minimise to execute only once.

Comment: please format your code to make it readable

Comment: You need to add an empty dependency array as the second parameter of useEffect function to avoid it being called on each render. Also, make sure to remove event listener once the job of the listener is done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
useEffect(() => {
  skylinkEventManager.addEventListener(events.ON_INCOMING_STREAM, response => { console.log('ON_INCOMING_STREAM', response, true);
  }, []);
```